# Crontab does not run my python script on my raspi

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

the python script does execute well manually through the terminal:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/AlarmClock/alarm.py
```

but it does not work automatically by the crontab. Here is the cronjob (crontab -e) in the /tmp/crontab.iGf7md/crontab file:

```
32 13 2 * * sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/AlarmClock/alarm.py
```

In the alarm.py script is no print command. The script only lights up a LED-Strip connected to the gpio-pin which works fine.

Does anyone know my mistake?

Comment: something's wrong with the time you use in crontab, the hour is set to 31 https://crontab.guru/#32_31_2_*_*

Answer (score 0):

From left to right, the parameters for `crontab` are:

*minute (0 -59)

*hour (0 -23)

*day of month (1 - 31)

*month (1 -12)

*day of week (0 -6, 0 = Sunday)

So, defining hour = 31 will not work. 
Have a look at [this quick reference guide](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

i think "32 31 2 * *" wrong.
"31" is represents hour and "23" must be the last value.
I hope it works if you fix it. 
[crontab generator](https://crontab.guru/) you might want to browse

Comment: yes you are right, but sorry for this i make it wrong. The right crontab is: 32 13 2 * * ..